# ASP.NET Core MVC view: Copying View and Repasting Code, Identifier Expected error received

Tags: c#, view, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to create a simple ASP.NET Core MVC app to display files in folder on webpage. I am getting an error

> Error: identifier expected in first line for view

How would I resolve this? It cannot seem to even compile my view.

**Service:**

```
public IEnumerable<string> FileDirectoryDisplay()
{
    return Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Desktop\SampleFolder", "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
}
```

**Controller:**

```
namespace filelist2.Controllers
{
    public class FileInfoController : Controller
    {
        // GET: FileInfo
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            FileInformation fileInformation = new FileInformation();
            var filetest = fileInformation.FileDirectoryDisplay();
            return View(filetest);
        }
    }
}
```

View: FileInfo\Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
@foreach (var element in Model)
{
    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(m => element)</p>
}
```

[image]

**Update:**

When 1) I deleted the View, 2) and copied another View, 3) and then repasted the actual View code I needed, it worked and recognized all the syntax. Keep having this issue on and off. Anyone know why this fix works?

Comment: I tried your code on my solution & it worked every time. You could try restarting Visual Studio & then do a Rebuild-all & see if the problem goes away. The view code is also compiled in to a *Views DLL - sometimes this can be out of sync with the actual View code.

Comment: Delete your `.vs` folder in your project file where you have saved your project and then build your code. it should compile successfully if there were no earlier errors to be resolved.

Comment: Did this work ?